TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transfer-encoding') at hasbody
I am working on a Matrimony_Backend (click the link to see the GitHub repo) with Hono, Cloudflare Worker, and Prisma.
I am trying to introduce an add profile_image feature and horoscope_img. Being quite new to Hono, I am puzzled about the problem I have run into.
The Profile Creation Router:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client/edge";
import { withAccelerate } from "@prisma/extension-accelerate"
import { Hono, Handler } from "hono";
import { ProfileSchema } from "../schema_validation";
import { uoloadOnCloudinary } from "../util/cloudinary";
import multer from "multer";

type Bindings = {
    DATABASE_URL: string;

}

const profileRouter = new Hono<{
    Bindings: Bindings
}>()

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './images');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const localFileSave = multer({ storage })

profileRouter.post('/create',localFileSave.fields([
    {
        name:'profile_image',
        maxCount: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'horoscope_img',
        maxCount: 1
    }
]) ,async (c) => {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient({
        datasourceUrl: c.env?.DATABASE_URL,
    }).$extends(withAccelerate());

    const body = await c.req.parseBody()
    console.log(body)
    const f1 = body["profile_image"]
    console.log(f1)


})
export default profileRouter

Package.json


{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "wrangler dev src/index.ts",
    "deploy": "wrangler deploy --minify src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hono-storage/node-disk": "^0.0.10",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.12.1",
    "@prisma/extension-accelerate": "^1.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^2.1.0",
    "hono": "^4.1.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "prisma": "^5.12.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20240208.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.5",
    "wrangler": "^3.32.0"
  }
}

localFileSave.fields([
    {
        name:'profile_image',
        maxCount: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'horoscope_img',
        maxCount: 1
    }
])  

also got an warning on above code :

No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'H<{ Bindings: Bindings; }, "/create", BlankInput, HandlerResponse<any>>'.
      Type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareHandler<{ Bindings: Bindings; }, "/create", BlankInput>'.
        Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 3 or more, but got 2.ts(2769)
types.d.ts(151, 5): The last overload is declared here.

What am I doing wrong?
